# swagger-tools on node: How to load swaggerUi?

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-tools

```
When I hit http://localhost:3001/api-docs loads the swagger json docs.

{
swagger: "2.0",
info: {
version: "1.0.0",
title: "Auth-gateway services",
contact: {
name: "swagger docs",
url: "https://www.google.com"
}
},
host: "127.0.0.1:3001",
basePath: "/",
...
}
```

But how do I load UI like http://petstore.swagger.io/ for my APIs.

Answer (score 0):

To view you api through swagger-ui, do one of the following.

**Option 1: Using online swagger-ui**

1. Go to [this](http://petstore.swagger.io/).
2. On the dialog-box on the top of the page, provide the url for swagger-json. In your case, insert **http://localhost:3001/api-docs** instead of http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json (which can be seen in default) and click **Explore**.
3. Now you can see swagger-ui generated for your api.

**Option 2: Setting up swagger-ui project locally**

You have to set up [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui). You can clone the project set up that with the below instructions provided.

```
Windows Users: Please install Python before follow below guidelines
for node-gyp rebuild to run.

1. npm install
2. npm run build
3. You should see the distribution under the dist folder. Open ./dist/index.html to launch Swagger UI in a browser

Development

Use npm run serve to make a new build, watch for changes, and serve the result at http://localhost:8080/.
```

Now you should be able to see something exactly like [online swagger-ui](http://petstore.swagger.io/).

Do the same as option 1 to provide swagger-json url and see swagger-ui generated.